Issues adapting Universal Music Translation Network code from META to Colab(or Kaggle) or virtualenv Miniconda environment on Colab
I'm working on experiments related to audio and music AI, and I came across the code developed by META over 5 years ago, known as the Universal Music Translation Network. This technology is fascinating as it allows translating music to another genre while maintaining the essential properties that define the original song.
My goal is to adapt this code to a Colab environment to conduct tests and experiments more accessible and collaboratively. However, I've encountered some problems that I haven't been able to solve so far.
Issue number 1: When attempting to run the code in Colab, everything goes smoothly until I reach a specific part of the code where it gets stuck and doesn't proceed. I've explored multiple possibilities, including installing Ninja, but I still haven't been able to unlock the code. I'm attaching the error I'm getting so that you can help me identify what's wrong. I'm also providing the Colab link for you to try and correct it.
Same issue in a Miniconda virtualenv: To try to solve the previous problem, I decided to try running the code in a virtual environment with Miniconda. I noticed that the original code was designed for Python 3.7, while Colab uses Python 3.10. However, when running it in a virtual environment with Python 3.7, the problem persists. I thought it could be some difference between the Python versions, but I can't identify the exact cause of the issue.
Resources:
Colab
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZWsNAKCaXPw4mtSkE_pAjf6kMHwrLJ_i?usp=sharing
Colab Miniconda ver
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12KU3BNcKZHcghivyvLD_YehONI7CLhBj?usp=sharing
GitHub Original
https://github.com/facebookresearch/music-translation.git

Alternative, Another Different code implementation of UMTN
Colab
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cJrLb_3LWp0b-jcTMdVXe0NagyZhvW_n?usp=sharing
GitHub Original
https://github.com/scpark20/universal-music-translation.git

CODE
print('Starting')
matplotlib.use('agg')

checkpoints = checkpoint.parent.glob(checkpoint.name + '_*.pth')
checkpoints = [c for c in checkpoints if extract_id(c) in decoders]
assert len(checkpoints) >= 1, "No checkpoints found."

model_args = torch.load(checkpoint.parent / 'args.pth')[0]
encoder = wavenet_models.Encoder(model_args)
encoder.load_state_dict(torch.load(checkpoints[0])['encoder_state'])
encoder.eval()
encoder = encoder.cuda()

decoders = []
decoder_ids = []
for checkpoint in checkpoints:
    decoder = WaveNet(model_args)
    decoder.load_state_dict(torch.load(checkpoint)['decoder_state'])
    decoder.eval()
    decoder = decoder.cuda()
    decoder = NVWavenetGenerator(decoder, rate * (split_size // 20), batch_size, 3)

    decoders += [decoder]
    decoder_ids += [extract_id(checkpoint)]


The error arises when I try to instantiate the NVWavenetGenerator object with the following line of code:
decoder = NVWavenetGenerator(decoder, rate * (split_size // 20), batch_size, 3)

ERROR GET:
Starting
Failed loading nv_wavenet_ext, building dynamically
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/content/music-translation/src/nv_wavenet_generator.py in __init__(self, model, sample_count, batch_size, implementation, cond_repeat)
     54         try:
---> 55             import nv_wavenet_ext
     56             self.wavenet_cu = nv_wavenet_ext

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nv_wavenet_ext'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
7 frames
CalledProcessError: Command '['ninja', '-v']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py in _run_ninja_build(build_directory, verbose, error_prefix)
   2110         if hasattr(error, 'output') and error.output:  # type: ignore[union-attr]
   2111             message += f": {error.output.decode(*SUBPROCESS_DECODE_ARGS)}"  # type: ignore[union-attr]
-> 2112         raise RuntimeError(message) from e
   2113 
   2114 

RuntimeError: Error building extension 'wavenet_cu_vh45id2x': [1/4] c++ -MMD -MF matrix.o.d -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=wavenet_cu_vh45id2x -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE=\"_gcc\" -DPYBIND11_STDLIB=\"_libstdcpp\" -DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI=\"_cxxabi1011\" -isystem /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include -isystem /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -isystem /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/TH -isystem /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/THC -isystem /usr/local/cuda/include -isystem /usr/include/python3.10 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -fPIC -std=c++17 -c /content/music-translation/src/nv-wavenet/matrix.cpp -o matrix.o 
[2/4] /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc --generate-dependencies-with-compile --dependency-output wavenet_infer.cuda.o.d -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=wavenet_cu_vh45id2x -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE=\"_gcc\" -DPYBIND11_STDLIB=\"_libstdcpp\" -DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI=\"_cxxabi1011\" -isystem /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include -isystem /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -isystem /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/TH -isystem /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/THC -isystem /usr/local/cuda/include -isystem /usr/include/python3.10 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_BFLOAT16_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ --expt-relaxed-constexpr -gencode=arch=compute_75,code=compute_75 -gencode=arch=compute_75,code=sm_75 --compiler-options '-fPIC' -arch=sm_70 -std=c++14 --use_fast_math -maxrregcount 128 --ptxas-options=-v --expt-relaxed-constexpr -D__GNUC__=6 -c /content/music-translation/src/nv-wavenet/wavenet_infer.cu -o wavenet_infer.cuda.o 
FAILED: wavenet_infer.cuda.o 
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc --generate-dependencies-with-compile --dependency-output wavenet_infer.cuda.o.d -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=wavenet_cu_vh45id2x -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE=\"_gcc\" -DPYBIND11_STDLIB=\"_libstdcpp\" -DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI=\"_cxxabi1011\" -isystem /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include -isystem /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -isystem /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/TH -isystem /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/THC -isystem /usr/local/cuda/include -isystem /usr/include/python3.10 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_BFLOAT16_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ --expt-relaxed-constexpr -gencode=arch=compute_75,code=compute_75 -gencode=arch=compute_75,code=sm_75 --compiler-options '-fPIC' -arch=sm_70 -std=c++14 --use_fast_math -maxrregcount 128 --ptxas-options=-v --expt-relaxed-constexpr -D__GNUC__=6 -c /content/music-translation/src/nv-wavenet/wavenet_infer.cu -o wavenet_infer.cuda.o 
<command-line>: warning: "__GNUC__" redefined
<built-in>: note: this is the location of the previous definition
<command-line>: warning: "__GNUC__" redefined
<built-in>: note: this is the location of the previous definition
<command-line>: warning: "__GNUC__" redefined
<built-in>: note: this is the location of the previous definition
/content/music-translation/src/nv-wavenet/matrix_math.cuh(48): error: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "float" to "__half"
      return f;
             ^

/content/music-translation/src/nv-wavenet/matrix_math.cuh(52): error: no suitable conversion function from "half" to "float" exists
      return __float2half(f);
                          ^

at::Tensor::data() const [with T = float]’ is deprecated: Tensor.data<T>() is deprecated. Please use Tensor.data_ptr<T>() instead. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   49 |     float* embedding_curr = embed_curr_tensor.data<float>();
      |                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
In file included from /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/Tensor.h:3,
                 from /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/ATen/Tensor.h:3,
                 from /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/autograd/function_hook.h:3,
                 from /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/autograd/cpp_hook.h:2,
                 from /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/autograd/variable.h:6,
                 from /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/autograd/autograd.h:3,
                 from /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/autograd.h:3,
                 from /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/TensorBody.h:247:7: note: declared here
  247 |   T * data() const {
      |       ^~~~
/content/music-translation/src/nv-wavenet/wavenet_infer_wrapper.cpp:119:66: warning: ‘T* at::Tensor::data() const [with T = float]’ is deprecated: Tensor.data<T>() is deprecated. Please use Tensor.data_ptr<T>() instead. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  119 |     float* output_selectors = output_selectors_tensor.data<float>();

This code represents a significant challenge for me and is preventing me from progressing in my studies. If anyone is interested in joining and providing assistance, I've made the links to the original Colabs I was adapting public. I suggest trying it first in Colab without Miniconda, as ultimately, the same problem arises. I would greatly appreciate it if someone manages to unlock the code and share it with the community.
